# Why those buttons won't get the text in the same position? (Relative to each button)

Tags: python, button, tkinter

Im trying to make a script generate buttons out of a txt file lines (Each line will be a button). It works ok (generates the buttons, same as the number of rows, each with the row as caption) but the text inside the buttons will be in different position (all but the last one will be in the upper side of the button, and the last one is well placed in the center of the button) but all of them share the same code. Interestingly enough, the values I get from the line:

```
print AuxName
```

Will be a number, which is the same number for all the loop but the starting one. The full code is this:

```
   from Tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
master = Tk()
master.wm_title("Window Title")
master.geometry("400x400")
tk_rgb = "#%02x%02x%02x" %  (128,128,128)
master.config( bg = tk_rgb)
filehandle = open('test.txt','r')
List = filehandle.readlines()
ListSize = len(List)
filehandle.close()
for x in range ( ListSize ):
    yy = 20*(x+1)
    AuxName = 'btn'+str(x)
    AuxName = Button(master, text=List[x], font=("arial", 10))
    tk_rgb = "#%02x%02x%02x" % (0,0,0)
    AuxName["fg"] = tk_rgb
    tk_rgb = "#%02x%02x%02x" % (255,255,255)
    AuxName["bg"] = tk_rgb
    AuxName.place(x=10, y=yy , height=20, width=200)
    print AuxName
    print yy
mainloop()
```

Summary question: How can I make all the buttons have the caption in the center of the button instead of in different position relative to itself as it happens now?

Comment: I don't see the problem you describe, I get the captions in the center of the buttons. Maybe the labels have trailing/leading whitespace? Try `..., text=List[x].strip(), ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code as posted works fine.

A guess as to why you're seeing what you're seeing is that the data in your file is causing the problem. Is it possible some lines have lots of leading or trailing whitespace?

Comment: Hi, I think an image can describe better what I get: http://i.imgur.com/5uRi6ds.png There you can see the caption I get on the buttons... And the text comes from a textfile I just created, nothing but the words and then no spaces at the end. Also changed the text to contain less lines, or more lines, and buttons will appear but same structure (last one will be the only one to appear correct caption). I changed the heigth to 20 since (instead of 40 ) since the error is easier to see. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @user2138906: If you use pack or grid instead of place, Tkinter will compute the proper height for you. My guess is that you have newlines or carriage returns in your data. Have you tried using `strip` on the text when creating the buttons?

Comment: Strip solved it, the list had a carriage return on each line but the last one, so thats why the buttons would also use that carriage return. Im impressed by your guess, and thankful for your help, its solved! :)